# How to retrieve data from postgresql using nodejs and display it on the same page where i made a request

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.1

I'm using this on server side:

```
app.get('/getdata', function(request, response) {
  client.query("SELECT time, name, assembly FROM timings order by time limit 10", function(err, results) {
    console.log(results.rows[0]);

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  //here i want to do something to send results to my html page
});
```

And this on client side html page

```
<form action="/getdata" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>
</form>
```

Also, help me with how I can display data on the same HTML page. And where i have to place my code because i'm new to nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this:

```
app.get('/getdata', function(request, response) {
  client.query("SELECT time, name, assembly FROM timings order by time limit 10", function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    response.send(results.rows); // assumes 'results.rows' can be serialized to JSON
  });
});
```

You can retrieve that information from your HTML page using an AJAX-request. Let's assume you use jQuery (error handling not included):

```
$.getJSON('/getdata', function(response) {
  // do something with the response, which should be the same as 'results.rows' above
});
```

Comment: Can you please help me with extracting data in html page. And i want data on the same page where i made request. This code taking me to a new page. Please help with this...

Comment: I've included some code which you can use in your HTML to retrieve the information. It assumes that you use jQuery and at least have some knowledge on how jQuery works.